# css clear in safari and chrome creates an extra line, not in firefox

Tags: html, css

Adding clear: left, clear: right, or clear:both to an element would create an extra carriage return in Firefox, but not in Chrome and Safari, it is very frustrating, anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What element are you adding it to?

Comment: You don't specify which behavior you consider broken, so it is hard to suggest a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding the style to the line break tag (`<br>`) then this will add a line break as should be expected. You could try using a div instead since they have zero height when there is no content:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.clear-nobr {clear:both;line-height:0!important;font-size:0!important;}
```